# inner element of <script> not recognized by document

Tags: javascript, html, innerhtml, getelementbyid

I have a template `<script>` tag that is holding some HTML code and
I want to replace the `label` text with a JS script.

```
<script type="text/template" id="element">
    <body>
        <label id="sub-element">Replace me</label>
    </body>
</script>
```

and right after it, I have some JavaScript:

```
<script> 
   let str = "Some text";
</script>
```

What would the best approach?

I've tried using `document.getElementById("sub-element").innerHTML` and it didn't do anything.

Thank you

Comment: Why don't you use a `<template>` element instead of `<script>`?

Comment: Why do you have body inside script tag. It works fine if you remove `script` tag

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Markup inside a script tag that's not interpreted to be JavaScript will be completely ignored. No `#sub-element` element exists in the DOM.

You can use DOMParser to turn the content into a document, change it as needed, then turn the document back into text and replace it in the template:

```js
const template = document.querySelector('#element');
const doc = new DOMParser().parseFromString(template.textContent, 'text/html');
doc.querySelector('#sub-element').textContent = 'Some text';
template.textContent = doc.body.outerHTML;
console.log(template.textContent);
```

```html
<script type="text/template" id="element">
    <body>
        <label id="sub-element">Replace me</label>
    </body>
</script>
```

But if you're planning on doing any nontrivial amount of something like this, I'd highly recommend using a framework instead to insert content into a template, instead of using manual DOM manipulation. For example, with React, you could do something like:

```js
const SomeLabel = ({ content }) => <label id="sub-element">{content}</label>;
const App = () => {
    return <SomeLabel content="Some Text" />;
};
ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.querySelector('.react'));
```

```html
<script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react@16/umd/react.development.js"></script>
<script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@16/umd/react-dom.development.js"></script>
<div class='react'></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<body>
<label id="sub-element">replace me</label>
<script>
    document.getElementById('sub-element').innerHTML = "new sentence";
</script>
</body>
```

maybe you can try this code